# Why is network status lost when I switch from Cellular to Wifi in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-connectivitymanager

I'm using connectivity manager to check if connection is available, lost, etc. This is my network repository impl

```
class NetworkRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context
) : NetworkRepository {

    private val connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    override val networkStatus: Flow<NetworkStatus> = callbackFlow {
        val connectivityCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                trySend(NetworkStatus.Available)
            }

            override fun onUnavailable() {
                trySend(NetworkStatus.Unavailable)
            }

            override fun onLosing(network: Network, maxMsToLive: Int) {
                trySend(NetworkStatus.Losing)
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                trySend(NetworkStatus.Lost)
            }
        }

        val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
            .build()

        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(request, connectivityCallback)

        awaitClose {
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(connectivityCallback)
        }
    }.distinctUntilChanged()
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
}
```

When I switch from wifi to cellular it's working. It works when only wifi is on or cellular. But that switch from cellular to wifi shows connectivity dialog for some reason